# System Settings -> Additional Drivers is empty. How then do I install proprietary drivers?

Tags: software-installation

I use Ubuntu 12.04. My graphics card is Geforce GT540M.

I opened Synaptic Package manager and installed the following:

- nvidia-common
- nvidia-settings-update
- nvidia-common
- nvidia-current
- nvidia-current-updates

The following were installed before(when unity launcher looked normal):

- jockey-common
- psensor
- nvidia-settings
- jockey-gtk
- xserver-xorg-video-nouveau

My intention was to use the right Nvidia drivers. 
But apparently it didn't rightly install the drivers and now I have **Unity 2D** running!

Comment: post some info about your graphics card. type `sudo lshw` in the terminal and post the appropriate part.

Comment: I'm sorry, what exactly should I post? Just GPU related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute on a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd>) `dpkg -l | grep nvidia-` to list all NVIDIA related packages.
Remove them all **except** nvidia-common, e.g. `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current nvidia-current-updates nvidia-settings-updates`.
Install **only** nvidia-current: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`.

[image: Install via the software center]

Reboot your computer.

Comment: Thanks, but this wouldn't work for me, since my card is an Optimus card and there are no proprietary drivers for it on linux.